# Error @ Database Connection Initialization : Error: database name must be a string

Tags: mongodb

i just try to connect mongodb. but it show

> Error @ Database Connection     Initialization : Error: database name
>   must be a string

Following is code:

```
try {
mongoDb.connect("localhost:27017/sample");
var db = mongoDb
}
catch (err) {
console.log('Error @ Database Connection Initialization : ' + err);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
// Initialize connection once
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/sample", function(err, database) {
  if(err) return console.error(err);

  db = database;

  // the Mongo driver recommends starting the server here because most apps *should* fail to start if they have no DB.  If yours is the exception, move the server startup elsewhere.
});
```